# Перегрузка [] в динамическом классе c++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов

```
class Dynarr
{
private:
   double * arr;
   int size;
public:
    double & operator[](int pos) {
       cout << " hey " <<  size << endl;
       return arr[pos];
    };
    Dynarr * operator=(Dynarr * rhs) {
       *this = Dynarr(rhs->size, rhs->arr);
    };
};
int main()
{
    double * darr = new double[5];
    darr[0] = 0;
    darr[1] = 1;
    darr[2] = 2;
    darr[3] = 3;
    darr[4] = 4;
    Dynarr * arrr1 = new Dynarr(5, darr);
cout << arrr1[1] << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Как в строке

```
cout << arrr1[1] << endl;
```

обратиться ко второму элементу массива `arr`?

Comment: `(*arrr1)[1]` так как `arrr1` является указателем на экземпляр класса с перегруженным оператором.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов, собственно, два: как вам уже написали,

```
(*arr1)[1]
```

и

```
arr1->operator[](1)
```

Но я бы еще хотел заметить, что стоит иметь два перегруженных оператора - один для константного объекта:

```
double & operator[](int pos) 
{
   cout << " hey " <<  size << endl;
   return arr[pos];
};
double operator[](int pos) const
{
   cout << " hey " <<  size << endl;
   return arr[pos];
};
```

Ну и - неплохо бы проверять, не выходит ли `pos` за границы массива.